# Qt webkit widget error

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I've managed to get qmake to compile the `.pro` file for webkit and trying to make a basic browser window, it just about build but the below error pops up?

```
Auto configuration failed
8744:error:02001015:system library:fopen:Is a directory:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:126:fopen('g:/test/openssl098u/openssl.cnf','rb')
8744:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:131:
8744:error:0E078002:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:system     lib:.\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:199:
QMutex: destroying locked mutex
```

Comment: I think I have to disable SSL support but not sure how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue by installing the openssl win32 binaeries found
[here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

Comment: when being ask where to install OpenSSL DLLs, choose "The Windows system directory". In my case I had to install "Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables" before "Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1g" (obtained from the same link above)