# QNetworkAccessManager crash related to SSL

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, qnetworkaccessmanager

My Qt Windows desktop application crashes on first QNetworkAccessManager->get call. I get following error in the log.

```
Auto configuration failed
16100:error:02001015:system library:fopen:Is a directory:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:122:fopen('d:/openssl/ssl/openssl.cnf','rb')
16100:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:127:
16100:error:0E078002:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:system lib:.\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:199:
```

It is something related to OpenSSL configuration, but I actually don't use (and don't need) SSL in my application. I know that OpenSSL library is loaded together with QNetworkAccessManager, but is there any way to disable it?

I can fix this problem by reinstalling openssl libraries like it is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526389/qt-webkit-widget-error), but this is not a good solution since I cannot force my customers to reinstall openssl on their systems because of my application. So I am looking for a better solution.
I already tried adding DEFINES += QT_NO_SSL into my project file but with no luck. Interesting here is that this is only happening after I deploy my application, it works smoothly from Qt Creator.

Important thing here is that I can manually manipulate crashing (on deploy systems) by modifying OPENSSL_CONF environment variable. If it does not exist or if it is set correctly, app won't crash, otherwise (env. variable is set to incorrect folder) app crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried unsetenv("OPENSSL_CONF") at application start?

Comment: No, but I tried it now and it actually does the trick. Thanks!